# use C++ functions in .so file which is also placed in .aar

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, .so

I have an Android project which is developed by using NDK. I have a A.cpp file inside cpp folder. For this project, I have imported another project as .aar library and dependent it for my first project.

So the project which is imported, is also developed by using NDK and it has B.cpp file. There are .so files for all arms (armeabi-v7a .etc) in this project. Now i want to call functions in B.cpp from A.cpp. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need the first SO file->A in the compile time of B.

Specifically in the linking stage. You cannot build a component B which links to A, without having no access to A in compile time.

Your library should link against A which you can manually extract from the aar, and you can use them for compile time, then ship your app by only providing your (B.so) file.